# To show that $\operatorname{Rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})=\operatorname{Nullity}(\mathbf{A})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem is:

> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $\mathbf{A}^{2} = \mathbf{A}$. If $\mathbf{I}$ denotes the identity matrix, then how do I prove the result: $$\operatorname{Rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})=\operatorname{Nullity}(\mathbf{A})$$

I have trivially shown by taking $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}$, but in general I do not know how to prove this, thanks for help.

Comment: Was it in JAM last year?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$
\mathbf{A}^{2} = \mathbf{A}
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\quad
\mathbf{A}^{2} - \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}_{n\times n}
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\quad
\mathbf{A} \left(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}\right) = \mathbf{0}_{n\times n}.
$$
Let $\mathbf{B} = (\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{I})$.
The above implies that every  vector in the range of $\mathbf{B}$ lies in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. Can you take it from there?

**Edit**: I am expanding the answer because it seems we need to clarify a few things. 
Why is it that the range of $\mathbf{B}$ lies in the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$?
Let $\mathbf{w}$ be any vector in the range of $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{B})$. This means that we can write $\mathbf{w}$ as a linear combination of the columns of $\mathbf{B}$, *i.e.*, there exists a $\mathbf{c}$ such that $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{c}$. But,
$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} 
=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{c}
= \mathbf{0}_{n\times n} \mathbf{c}
= \mathbf{0},
$$
which implies that $\mathbf{w}$ belongs to the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})$.
Hence, we have shown that
$$
\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{B})
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}),
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{B}) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}).
$$
The above implies that
$$
\text{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) \ge \text{rank}(\mathbf{B})=\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}).
$$
But we are not quite done yet, since we want to show that the two sides are actually equal.

I am assuming that you should be familiar with the *Rank-Nullity Theorem*. How can you use that to show the other side of the inequality.

**Edit 2**: (This is the point where hints start looking a lot like an answer!)
The  *Rank-Nullity Theorem* theorem says that
$$
 n = \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}) + \text{nullity}(\mathbf{A})
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\text{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) = n - \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}).
$$
What can you say about $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{I})$ with respect to $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A})$? How can you get it into the picture? (Remember! we are trying to show that $\text{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) \le \text{rank}(\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{I})$ because we have already shown the reverse inequality.)

**Edit 3**:
We have already shown that 
$\text{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) \ge \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})$.
To show that the relation holds with equality, it suffices to show that 
$$
\text{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) \le \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}).
$$
We have already seen that
$$
\text{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) = n - \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}).
$$
Hence, to show the desired result, it suffices to show that
$$
n - \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}) \le \text{rank}(\mathbf{A}−\mathbf{I}).
$$
One way to argue about this, possibly not the best, is the following.
Let $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{I}$. By the rank-nullity theorem, we know that
$$
\text{rank}(\mathbf{B})
+
\text{nullity}(\mathbf{B}) = n.
$$
Now, the nullspace of $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{B})$, consists of all vectors $\mathbf{w}$ such that $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}$, or equivalently:
$$
\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{B})
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\quad
(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}
\quad
\Leftrightarrow
\quad
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w}.
$$
These vectors $\mathbf{w}$ are clearly just a subset of the range of $\mathbf{A}$.
In other words,
$$
\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{B})
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}),
$$
and in turn,
$
\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{B})
\subseteq
\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}).
$
We conclude that $\text{nullity}(\mathbf{B}) \le \text{rank}(\mathbf{A})$ and finally,
$$
\text{rank}(\mathbf{B}) 
= n-\text{nullity}(\mathbf{B})
\ge n-\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}),
$$
which is the desired inequality
$$
\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}) \ge n-\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}).
$$

Comment: thanks foranswer , i have almost got it , but how is that AB=O implies range of b lies in null spzce of A

Comment: Let $\mathbf{b}_{1}, \dots, \mathbf{b}_{m}$ be the columns of $\mathbf{B}$. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{0}_{n \times n}$ implies that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{b}_{i}= \mathbf{0}$, $\forall i$. So $\mathbf{b}_{i} \in \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})$. Do you agree? What about all vectors that are linear combinations of the $\mathbf{b}_{i}$s?

Comment: Well still not certain about it

Comment: Tell me what confuses you and we can take if from there. What is the part you feel uncertain about?

Comment: For a LT,  i know T (x) = Ax , for kernel setting Ax=0 and x lies in null space of A , Are you utilizing this fact but i am not certain

Comment: Exactly. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{b}_{1} = \mathbf{0}$ is equivalent to saying that $\mathbf{b}_{1}$ belongs to the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. Now, let also $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{b}_{2} = \mathbf{0}$. Then, if you take any linear combination $\mathbf{w}=c_{1}\mathbf{b}_{1} + c_{2}\mathbf{b}_{2}$, you can see that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}$ as well. Generalizing this to all $m$ vectors $\mathbf{b}_{i}$, we can conclude that all vectors in the range of $\mathbf{B}$ belong to the nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$. Note that we have not finished proving what we want. This is just a start!

Comment: If for any matrix multiplication AB=0 , its is disguise that B is in null space of A ., Secondly i thought proof is over

Comment: I am familiar with rank ullity theorem,but i donot know how to prove equality , hints?

Comment: Doesnot rank of A-Idepends upon rank of A

Comment: Yes, of course. But you can say something about it: $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{I}) \ge n - \text{rank}(\mathbf{A})$.

Comment: Why is that so.

Comment: @godonichia Sorry for the delayed response. I have updated the answer to show that last inequality as well.

Answer (score 3):

here is what i think is a shorter proof of $$ A^2 = A \implies ker(A) = image(A-I)  $$

proof: write $A^2 = A$ as $A(A-I) = 0$ this means that every column of $A-I$ is in $ker(A),$ therefore $image(A-I) \subset ker(A).$

to show the other direction, pick $x \in ker(A),$ so that $Ax = 0.$ 
then $x = x - Ax = (I-A)x$ that is $x \in image(A-I)$ that proves $\ker(A) \subset image(A-I)$

now the result $$rank(A-I) = dim(ker(A)) = nullity(A)$$  follows.

p.s.: this seems too good to be true. i hope i did not make any logical errors.

Comment: I think you meant every column of $A-I$ is in $ker(A)$.

Comment: @m.a., thanks. yes that is a typo, fixed now.